# How to return all labels and scores in SageMaker Inference?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nlp, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I am using the `HuggingFacePredictor` from `sagemaker.huggingface` to inference some text and I would like to get all label scores.

Is there any way of getting, as response from the endpoint:

```json
{
    "labels": ["help", "Greeting", "Farewell"] ,
    "score": [0.81, 0.1, 0.09],
}
```

(or similar)

Instead of:

```json
{
    "label": "help",
    "score": 0.81,
}
```

Here is some example code:

```py
import boto3

from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFacePredictor
from sagemaker.session import Session

sagemaker_session = Session(boto_session=boto3.session.Session())

predictor = HuggingFacePredictor(
    endpoint_name=project, sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
)
prediciton = predictor.predict({"inputs": text})[0]
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code sample, it is not quite clear what specific task you are performing, but for the sake of this answer, I'll assume you're doing text classification.

Most importantly, though, we can read the following in [Huggingface's Sagemaker reference document](https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/reference#inference-toolkit-api) (bold highlight by me):

> The Inference Toolkit accepts inputs in the inputs key, and **supports additional `pipelines` parameters in the `parameters` key**. You can provide any of the supported `kwargs` from `pipelines` as parameters.

If we check out the [accepted arguments by the `TextClassificationPipeline`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.2/en/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.TextClassificationPipeline.__call__), we can see that there is indeed one that returns all samples:

> `return_all_scores` (bool, optional, defaults to False) — Whether to return scores for all labels.

While I unfortunately don't have access to Sagemaker inference, I can run a sample to illustrate the output with a local pipeline:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
# uses 2-way sentiment classification model per default
pipe = pipeline("text-classification") 

pipe("I am really angry right now >:(", return_all_scores=True)
# Output: [[{'label': 'NEGATIVE', 'score': 0.9989138841629028},
#           {'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.0010860705515369773}]]
```

Based on the slightly different input format expected by Sagemaker, coupled with the example given in [this notebook](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/sagemaker/10_deploy_model_from_s3/deploy_transformer_model_from_s3.ipynb), I would assume that a corrected input in your own example code should look like this:

```json
{
    "inputs": text,
    "parameters": {"return_all_scores": True}
}
```

Comment: I understand how I can use this transformers pipeline to return all scores locally. But how should I use this pipeline in SageMaker? I don't see any parameter of Endpoint or EndpointConfig where I can define it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Endpoint or EndpointConfig? As I said, the last example of the JSON/dict object should be a drop-in replacement for the dict that you pass in your example code. In case it throws an error message, please update your question accordingly.

Comment: I want the SageMaker endpoint to return the scores for all labels. The code you published does exactly what I want, but for a model in a local environment and without any relation with SageMaker. I've been investigating and it seems there is no way of using this transformers pipeline on SageMaker for inference.

Comment: Again, the last snippet is a dictionary which you can replace in your own code, and it has nothing to do with the offline pipeline. The pipeline parameters can be specified in sagemaker as well, I just wanted to illustrate the fact that this parameter works as intended, that's why I chose to add the first code snippet. :)